# Transparency in TImage

Tags: delphi, timage

When a new TImage is created it is transparent. After drawing objects to this image I would like to clear them. Note that I need to keep the image transparent as the TImage is being used as an overlay to another image.

Some sort of "clear" function for the TImage would be best. I think I'm missing something simple here, I just could not find any clear function within the TImage menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not really meant to *draw* things on a `TImage` control. You're meant to assign its `Picture` property and leave it alone. In fact, when you draw on a `TImage`, you're either drawing transiently by drawing on its `Canvas` property, or you're modifying the underlying `Picture` object by drawing on *its* canvas.

To clear a `TImage`, simply unassign the `Picture` property.

```
Image.Picture := nil;
```

To draw transient images — something you'll need to repaint whenever the window gets obscured and revealed — use a `TPaintBox`.